# GWT : cell tree and initial keyboard selected node

Tags: gwt

I'm using a CellTree with the KeyboardSelectionPolicy.BOUND_TO_SELECTION.

I'd like to open the tree with a given path selected.

The code opening the child path and selecting the node is working fine when KeyboardSelectionPolicy is ENABLED/DISABLED but when BOUND_TO_SELECTION I can see that the keyboard-selected-node in the tree is never updated from : cellTree.selectionModel.setSelected( ... )

So I'm wondering if setSelected can work with BOUND_TO_SELECTION and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6310

I suppose you could find a way to call `setKeyboardSelectedRow` in response to `SelectionChangeEvent`s.

Comment: I'm using a CellTree and not a CellTable - I've tried already to hack into the CellTree impl. but with no success as not able to access base field/methods.